# Match and move cell data in excel

Tags: excel

I need a script that matches and moves email addresses in the right place i.e. next to their corresponding phone number.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You need index(match, match) and left.

Comment: Will the phone number always match the email?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea - if it is possible, build a new column in f, to get the left part of the mails up to the @. Then in column D write something like this:

```
=INDEX(F1:F8;Match(C2;F1:F8;0))
```

and it would work out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!

Here's the working solution:

Just insert it in Col. D

=INDEX($E$2:$E$4,MATCH(C2&"*@*",$E$2:$E$4,0))